# Easy way to draw a line chart in Core Plot?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

Is there an easy way to draw a line chart in Core Plot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of examples included with Core Plot [here](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/browse/#hg/examples).

Answer (score 0):

You can use S7graphView .Its simple to draw line chart. http://code.google.com/p/s7graphview/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need and the scale of your project I'd rather stick with Core Plot..
It's way more active, comprehensive and better documented than S7graphView.